# Sharing my screen to other people on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, screen-sharing

What would one suggest for remote teaching software for Ubuntu? I mean, if I would like to teach someone for example Python programming, pupil would see what I'm doing on my computer and hear my voice.

Comment: Welcome @remotetutor, if you'd list what you are looking for specific, especially if there are tools you've already tried and ruled out, it might help the community to focus suggestions that are best tailored to your request.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [zoom.us](https://zoom.us/). Zoom is a video conferencing solution like Hangouts and various others. The difference is that it has a native app for Ubuntu and other distributions.

On the settings page, you'll want to enable *Join from your browser* link. This way the recipient *does not* have to download the app. However, they may have a better experience if they also download and install zoom on their computer.

[image: Join from browser]